# Product Database and Application

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have simple application design it by C# (windows form application) and the database is Microsoft Access, it work with multi users.

We have Share Drive in our PC ,I put the application and database on the share drive.

How can I protect the application and the database from the users until they do not delete or open it?

Comment: With a Microsoft Access database, your protection abilities are pretty limited.

Comment: Sharing an Access database on a network share is basically the least secure way of using a database.  Switching to a real RDBMS (such as SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc.) is recommended for long-term development and security.  Access was designed to be a single-user, easy-to-use DB for simple projects, not as an enterprise system.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access is designed to be slightly better then storing this stuff in Excel Tables, but not so good it will ruin the MS Business with SQL Server. If anything, it is about getting you "hooked on" using Databases.

I think this project plainly went past the scale that Access can support. You need to go to a proper Database Server to go any further - user rights included. SQL Server Express and MySQL should both be avalible and free of charge. And of course there are tons of other Options.

Comment: Right but Are there way I can use Access?

Comment: @AhmedAlzaed Not securely, no.  That's why you have several people suggesting you switch to a "real" database system.

Comment: @AhmedAlzaed It should be easy to import the existing Data in the DB Server. MS SQL propably has a function for that. Or access should be able to export as CSV.